# Storing Data and at the same time updating data on a different table in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, 'vehicles' and 'assign_vehicles'. Whenever I assign a vehicle to a driver, I want the 'status' column on the 'vehicles' table to be updated to 'assigned'. How do I go about it?

Comment: How do you assign a vehicle? Using `->attach()` method or something else? Do you have a model for the `assign_vehicles` table?

Answer (score 0):

There is some assumptions to be made. You will have to have classes that looks similar to this.

```
public class Vechicle extends Model {
    public function assigned()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AssignVehicle::class);
    }
}

public class AssignVehicle {
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
    }
}
```

You can monitor the `AssignVehicle` event and add it to your boot method. Add it in `AssignVehicle.php` class. From there access the vehicle and update the status. Note there is a creating and created event, creating is before saving to the database and created is after saving to the database

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function (AssignVehicle $assignVehicle) {
        $assignVehicle->vehicle->status = 'assigned';
        $assignVehicle->vehicle->save();
    });
}
```

For this to trigger remember to use standard `Laravel` approaches for events to trigger. The following will work.

```
AssignVehicle::create([
    'vehicle_id' => $vehicle->id,
    // your fields
])
```